# How to multithread reading a file in c++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I have a big file, and i have to read it by chunk. Each time when i read a chunk, i have to do some time consuming operation, so i think multithread reading might help, each thread reads a chunk one by one and does its operation. here is my code in c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
const int CHAR_PER_FILE = 1e8;
const int NUM_THREAD = 2;
int order = -1;
bool is_reading = false;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable file_not_reading;
void partition(ifstream& is)
{
    while (is.peek() != EOF)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        while (is_reading)
            file_not_reading.wait(lock);

        is_reading = true;
        char *c = new char[CHAR_PER_FILE];

        is.read(c, CHAR_PER_FILE);
        order++;

        is_reading = false;

        file_not_reading.notify_all();
        lock.unlock();

        char oc[3];
        sprintf(oc, "%d", order);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));//some operations that take long time
        ofstream os(oc, ios::binary);
        os.write(c, CHAR_PER_FILE);
        delete[] c;
        os.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream is("bigfile.txt",ios::binary);
    thread threads[NUM_THREAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
        threads[i] = thread(partition, ref(is));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
        threads[i].join();

    is.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But my code didn't work, it only created 4 files instead of `bigfilesize/CHAR_PER_FILE, and threads seem got stuck, how can i make it work?

Is there any c++11 multithread reading file implementation or example?

Thanks.

Comment: `sprintf(oc, "%d", order);` being unprotected means that `order` may have been incremented since the unlock and the name very possibly not unique. And you're not doing any error checking on `is.read`, so you may be writing garbage.

Comment: A few thread-safety issues here. Shared globals need to be `volatile`.  `ifstream` is not thread safe but it's referred to outside the mutex - open a separate `ifstream` for each thread.

Comment: @AndyBrown There is no point of making these variables volatile. It doesn't help with threading problems. See http://herbsutter.com/2009/01/12/effective-concurrency-volatile-vs-volatile/ for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't get it, both `order` and `is` are locked, so i think they are safe.

Comment: @user1024 You lock, increment `order`, and unlock. So far, so good. But when you use `order` to build the filename, some other thread may have incremented it, since that is in the unlocked part. The problem with `is` is unrelated to the lock — you write your buffer even if reading failed.

Answer (score 10):

My advice:

- Use one thread to read chunks from the file. Every time a chunk is read, post it to a request queue. It is not worth reading multithreaded as there will be internal locks/blocking reading a common resource.
- Use a pool of threads. Each of them read from the queue, retrieves a chunk, execute the expensive operation and go back to wait for a new request.
- The queue must be mutex protected.
- Don't use more threads than the number of processing units (CPU/Cores/HyperThreads) you have.
- The main caveat of the above is that it will not guarantee the processing order. You will probably need to post the results to a central place that can reorder (again central place -> must be mutex protected).

Comment: Well, my current way is what you said, but i have to store these chunks in a repo, it needs more memory, so i think read the file and execute the expensive operation might be a better way.

Answer (score 5):

You could use task-based parallelism with std::async:

```
class result; // result of expensive operation
result expensive_operation(std::vector<char> const& data)
{
 result r = // long computation
 return r;
}

std::vector<char>::size_type BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;

std::vector<std::future<result>> partition(ifstream& in)
{
    std::vector<std::future<result>> tasks;

    while (!in.eof() && !in.fail())
    {
        std::vector<char> c(BLOCK_SIZE);
        is.read(c.data(), BLOCK_SIZE);
        c.resize(in.gcount());
        tasks.push_back( std::async( [](std::vector<char> data) 
        {
            return expensive_operation(data);
        },
        std::move(c) ));
    }
    return tasks;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream is("bigfile.txt",ios::binary);
    auto results = partition(is);

    // iterate over results and do something with it
}
```

Comment: your implementation is  good, but how can i control how many threads to create?

Comment: @user1024 I think you don't. One of the main points of std::async is to let the plattform decide when to spawn a new thread. I think on Windows it uses PPL and a thread pool.If you are on Windows, take a look at the PPL. It contains a better task-parallelism framework with parallel algorithms. On Linux, I recommend to look at Intel TBB which provides the same. Both have parallel_for and parallel_reduce.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file have to be read in "sequential" order, i.e. do the chunks have to be "operated" on in a special order? Otherwise you could e.g. make 4 threads and let each thread read 1/4 of the file (you could do this by using tellg and saving the position in e.g. a vector or variable). That way you wouldn't have to use locks.

Maybe you could tell us how the data you read in has to be evaluated.

Comment: I have considered your way, but every thread has to open the file and find the correct reading position, it would be a little thorny. And i don't know the performance of tellg.

Comment: I see. Have you considered using an Active Object model (basically a threadsafe queue + Async calls + Command-Pattern)? It can be a bit tricky to implement, but if you need to use multithreading often in your program, it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
void partition(ifstream& is)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::vector<char> c(CHAR_PER_FILE);
    is.read(c.data(), CHAR_PER_FILE);
    lock.unlock();

    if (is.fail() && !is.eof()) return;
    size_t num_bytes_read = is.gcount();

    std::ostringstream oc;
    oc << order;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000)); //take long time
    if (std::ofstream os(oc, ios::binary))
        os.write(c.data(), CHAR_PER_FILE);
}
```

Notes:

- The mutex serialises the operations already - no need for a condition variable.
- I've added a little input error and bytes-read handling - you should check after `os.write()` too, add an `else` for failed `ofstream` creation etc.

Comment: Thanks for your code, but it is slow. Is that because when A is reading, B is blocked, after A is done, B is still blocked. Do we have to manually notify            B? BTW, in your implementation, one thread only reads once, if i don't know the file size, how can i decide how many threads to create?

Comment: @user1024 you've launched into this with either very little analysis, or not shared whatever analysis you did with us.  It may be that the I/O is only taking a tiny fraction of the overall time, and there's hardly anything to be gained by having most of it done in parallel with processing.  You should see how long it takes just to read the data without processing (both when none of it is in cache, and when as much as will fit is cached), and consider whether this whole idea is misguided.  As for your questions, as one unlocks the OS will wake the next thread blocked on the lock.

Comment: And - please don't call it "my implementation" - I simply fixed some bugs in your implementation, hoping you'd learn something from that.  If I were writing my own implementation, I'd do things quite differently - having one thread do all the I/O (as if it's on the same physical device threading it simply forces seeks that could easily slow down the I/O), then having that thread hand over the work to other threads in whatever block size seems to make sense.  This is similar to what jsantander recommended.